# MySQL - How to use (LEFT) JOIN to join two tables via one table together?

Tags: php, mysql, join

## Some background and objective

I was putting together a link list for a person on my website in **HTML/PHP**. It allows multiple selections (select with attribute "multiple") and it basically looks like this:

```
╔══════════╗
║ Facebook ║
╠══════════╣
║ Google+  ║
╠══════════╣
║ Twitter  ║
╚══════════╝
```

Selected items will be saved into a MySQL database, but that is not all. After saving the selections I would like to go back and see, which selections were selected. This means I have to generate this **select**-element in PHP with the selections I selected.

## Structure of the database

**Last edited on 6.24.2015 at 13:23 (time in Finland)**

In **MySQL**, I have the following tables:

1. **link** includes link specific information (link address, color, etc.)
2. **person** includes information about a person (first and last name, address, email, etc.)
3. **person_link** serves as table to connect tables *link* and *person* together (has columns *id_link* and *id_person*)

The tables look as follows (have tried to display columns relevant to this question; data is arbitrary and is here for the sake of demonstration):

**link**

```
╔══════════╦════════════╗
║ id       ║ name       ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║ 1        ║ Facebook   ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║ 2        ║ Google+    ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║ 3        ║ Twitter    ║
╚══════════╩════════════╝
```

**person**

```
╔══════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦══════════════╦═════════════════╗
║ id       ║ name_first  ║ name_last   ║ address      ║ email           ║
╠══════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 1        ║ Jack        ║ Johnson     ║ Wacko Street ║ NULL            ║
╠══════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2        ║ Hanna       ║ Hill        ║ Hill Town    ║ hh@gmail.com    ║
╠══════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 3        ║ Eric        ║ Samson      ║ Wacko Street ║ NULL            ║
╚══════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩══════════════╩═════════════════╝
```

**person_link**

```
╔═══════════╦═════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ id_person ║ id_link ║ address             ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 2         ║ 1       ║ www.example.com     ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 2         ║ 2       ║ www.hello.org       ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

## The problem

In short, my problem is that I'm not able to put together a proper query in MySQL to achieve the desired goal. I've seen many questions regarding LEFT JOIN between two tables, but haven't come across a question with an additional table connecting two tables together.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT link.name, person.id
    FROM link
        LEFT JOIN person_link ON (link.id = person_link.id_link)
        JOIN person ON (person_link.id_person = person.id)
    WHERE person.id = 2
```

Now, I would expect this kind of query to list all links on the left and juxtapose an id of specific person on the right (if it is available). If an id matches a link, then this link has been selected from the **select**-element. This is what I wanted the result to look like (NULL represents the lack of match):

```
╔══════════╦══════╗
║ Facebook ║  2   ║
╠══════════╬══════╣
║ Google+  ║  2   ║
╠══════════╬══════╣
║ Twitter  ║ NULL ║
╚══════════╩══════╝
```

Why would I want the table to look like this? Because based on this table I could generate select-element to look like this:

```
╔═════════════════════╗
║ Facebook (SELECTED) ║
╠═════════════════════╣
║ Google+  (SELECTED) ║
╠═════════════════════╣
║ Twitter             ║
╚═════════════════════╝
```

But, instead of query being successful, I ended up with this:

```
╔══════════╦══════╗
║ Facebook ║  2   ║
╠══════════╬══════╣
║ Google+  ║  2   ║
╚══════════╩══════╝
```

There is obviously something wrong in my query, but I don't know what it is. So, my question is, *how to use (LEFT) JOIN to join two tables via one table together?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT l.name, p.id
FROM link l
LEFT JOIN person_link pl 
    ON (l.id = pl.id_link)
LEFT JOIN person p 
    ON (pl.id_person = p.id && l.id = pl.id_link && p.id = 2) 
group by l.link
```

or based on Nirala's answer

```
SELECT l.name, pl.id_person
FROM link l
LEFT JOIN person_link pl 
    ON (l.id = pl.id_link && pl.id_person = 2)
group by l.link
```

Comment: Well, this worked. Now I'm wondering why. Would like to learn, not just downright copy and paste. Still learning. :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow the person to be NULL:

```
SELECT link.name, person.id
FROM link
LEFT JOIN person_link ON (link.id = person_link.id_link)
LEFT JOIN person ON (person_link.id_person = person.id)
WHERE (person.id = 2 OR person.id IS NULL)
```

You can also write this as :

```
SELECT link.name, person.id
FROM link
LEFT JOIN person_link ON (link.id = person_link.id_link)
LEFT JOIN person ON (person_link.id_person = person.id AND person.id = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you

```
SELECT link.name, person_link.id_person FROM link LEFT JOIN person_link 
ON link.id = person_link.id_link WHERE person_link.id_person = 2
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems to output the incorrect result I already posted in my question. I wonder if primary key, which consists of id_link and id_person in person_link-table could be an issue? Also, could you provide an explanation as to why this should work instead of the query I provided?

Comment: This is more optimized query. If you are getting your desired result within two tables than why would you query 3 tables.

Comment: The reason I am utilizing 3 tables is because the number of links each person can have is able to vary. It would not make sense to set each link type as its own column in the person-table. Instead, I would use person_link-table to connect a person to his list of links. Does this make sense? If not, would you recommend a better approach? :0

Comment: You havn't mentioned these ol stuff in your question. I have just just optimized your query, you may modify my query based on your needs.

Comment: You show us table structure for all three tables and desired result set, I will give you exact query. Ok?

Comment: That might be the case. I'll see what I can do to improve upon the question. Thanks for you effort! :)

Comment: You Welcome. You can try this : SELECT l.name,p.person FROM((link AS l LEFT JOIN person_link AS pl ON l.id=pl.id_link) LEFT JOIN person ON pl.id_person=person.id) WHERE p.id = 2

Comment: Edited the question to display the table structure better. Hope it's more edifying now! :D

Answer (score 0):

Some sample data would be nice (http://sqlfiddle.com/ would be perfect), but from my perspective this untested query should do the job.

```
SELECT person.*, link.* 
FROM person_link 
RIGHT JOIN link ON id_link = link.id 
INNER JOIN person ON id_person = person.id
WHERE id_person = 2
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks for mentioning SQLFiddle. Seems like a handy tool while asking questions. :)